# How to cache the result of an inherited function before overriding it

Tags: solidity-0.8.x, inheritance, override

```
contract A {

    function getUINT() public virtual view returns (uint) {
        return 100000;
    }
}

contract B is A {

    uint trycache;
    uint public trycache2 = getUINT(); // still 200000
    constructor () {
        trycache = getUINT(); // 200000
    }

    function getUINT() public view virtual /* defer */ override returns (uint) {
        return 200000;
    }

    function returncached() public view returns (uint) {
        return trycache;
    }
}
```

Trying to cache contract A's value fails. Overriding functions happens immediately even before initialization. Yes I know I can use an internal variable in the parent contract, but that's additional abstraction that I would rather avoid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `super` keyword to retrieve the original version of the function that you're overriding.

The `super` keyword in Solidity gives access to the immediate parent contract from which the current contract is derived.

https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/contracts.html#inheritance#super

```
contract A {

    function getUINT() public virtual view returns (uint) {
        return 100000;
    }
}

contract B is A {

    uint trycache;
    uint public trycache2 = super.getUINT(); // now 100000
    constructor () {
        trycache = super.getUINT(); // 100000
    }

    function getUINT() public view virtual /* defer */ override returns (uint) {
        return 200000;
    }

    function returncached() public view returns (uint) {
        return trycache;
    }
}
```